# Unhandled exception in face detection

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I am using the  code [cascade classifier for face detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)  (and sometimes other code as well). But the program terminates at the line:

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
```

basically at  `size(30,30);`. The error it gives is  "unhandled exception" , and further more at "opencv_objdetectd.dll". I have searched  on the internet but haven't been able to find a similar issue or solution. I would appreciate any help, as I have been stuck in this for many days now.

Comment: You must provide more code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: here is link to the code . i have  not changed anything in it 

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

Comment: If it's a problem with Size(30, 30) you can try moving it to its own line. However I assume it's an ordinary struct which means it's crashing on a memory allocation which could mean that you've written over memory at some earlier point.

Comment: so what should i do .. like i said    i have removed any other code ..and am  running only  code for face detection.what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

'unhandled exceptions' never come from the opencv codebase.

the issue might not be the code, but other, like using debug dlls in release mode or the other way round, wrong 32/64 bit dlls, and such.

i just don't believe you, that Size(30,30) is the issue. try :

`face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces );` //there's default args for the rest

cascade-detection most often it fails for one of 2 reasons:

1. the haar-cascade was not found. check that.

   if( ! face_cascade.load("bla.xml") )
   {
      // error
   }
2. your image is invalid

   if ( frame_gray.empty() )
   {
      // error
   }

Comment: m sure  the version are right bcz  have previously used the libraries with  contour finding .  can u please mention  the dll or other requirement s.may be i am missing something.  i have used 
imageproc, highgui, core ,objdetect  .. all debug version from X86 ,vc10  folder ...